# MediaPlayer error -2147483648 when playing mp3 file online on android 2.3

Tags: android, media-player

Want to play audio/mp3 files online but unable to prepare medplayer. Code given below,

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
mediaPlayer1.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                String p=URL+"/"+ AudioFile_Name;
                mediaPlayer1.setDataSource(p);
                mediaPlayer1.prepareAsync();
                mediaPlayer1.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            //Now dismis progress dialog, Media palyer will start playing
                            mp.start();
                        }
                    });
mediaPlayer1.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                            // dissmiss progress bar here. It will come here when MediaPlayer
                            //  is not able to play file. You can show error message to user
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

Please advise soloution,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was getting this problem as I have stored my files in Dropbox and its shared address is secured website means Https which is not supported in androd 2.3, now changed to http and its working.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you used Internet permisstion in manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: am able to download files and play them from sd-card, problem is only when playng online. Permsson s available in manifest